# Cache data from external api with rails or ember?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, postgresql, caching, ember.js

I have an ember/rails application with three main templates, Home, Contacts, and Payments.  Both the contacts and payments templates need an array of contacts.  This array needs to be populated from an external api.  Currently, for the contacts every time I am going to this template the external api is being hit.  Ideally I would like to hit the api asynchronously when a user first signs in, grabs this data once and can refer back to it without hitting the external api until necessary.

With rails I could easily just add has_one :contacts_list for user with a postgres json column  and when switching the templates conditionally refresh this whenever needed.  I am curious as to the best way to deal with this problem in ember.

Comment: are you using ember data or plain old ajax?

Comment: I am using ember data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a DS.Model for 'contact' and use a has_many on Contacts and Payments model. Then, you could specify 'async: true' like

```
DS.hasMany('contact', {async: true}),
```

This will load the contacts asynchronously if they have not been loaded already. If they have been loaded, it will simply return the loaded contacts.

I am assuming that you have the following models: Contacts, Payments.

Comment: Yes I have those models but really currentUser has_many contacts and payments.  If, for example, I set up the async: true has_many relationship off of the currentUser and my rails contacts index action had this code `Venmo.new(current_user.venmo_token, current_user.venmo_id).get_contacts.to_json` this method would only be hit once and then cached in ember?

Comment: so if you have the models like 'currentUser', 'contacts' and 'payments' and have a has_many on both contacts and payments specified in the model, then specifying async true on those will only load them when your code tries to access something in them, like currentUser.payments.length for example, then an ajax request will be made to your payments/index action, iff payments has not been loaded already.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the `setupController` method on a route to do this type of caching.  Just check to see if the content is already available, and only load it if it's not there. Something like this:

```
App.ContactsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController : function(controller,model){
    if(!controller.get('content')){
      this.store.find('contact').then(function(contacts){
        controller.set('content',contacts)
      });
    }
  }
});
```